# Python reformat namedtuple argument value

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability, dry, namedtuple

My code receives a json which I then turn into a dictionary. I want to create a class from that dictionary so that my IDE can check for a typo when the attributes are used. Moreover, I want to change the attribute called `date` to be of type `date` instead of `string`. I can create a class myself but I thought using `namedtuple` would be nicer and shorter.

I have the following code, which raises `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. The reason is that `namedtuple` is immutable (same as `tuple`), so `instance.date` cannot be changed after `instance` is created. Note that there are a lot more attributes, this is just a simple example.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime

class Payment(namedtuple("_Payment", ["date", "amount"])):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.date = datetime.strptime(instance.date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return instance

p = Payment(**{"date": "2017-05-06", "amount": 100})
```

I can search for `date` in `kwargs` and in `args` and manipulate it, but this seems a bit ugly. Another solution is to define the arguments of `__new__` explicitly so that I can manipulate `date` easily. I don't like this solution because of the DRY principle: I do not want to state the names of the fields twice (once for `namedtuple` and once for `__new__`). Ideally, I could define the field names just once and use them as arguments to `namedtuple` and also as the arguments of `__new__`. But I don't think there is a way to use a tuple as the list of arguments of a function, in a way similar to this:

```
PAYMENT_FIELDS = ("date", "amount")
class Payment(namedtuple("_Payment", PAYMENT_FIELDS)):
    def __new__(cls, PAYMENT_FIELDS)
        ...
```

A partial solution is to define:

```
class Payment(namedtuple("_Payment", ["date", "amount"])):
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        d["date"] = datetime.strptime(d["date"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return cls(**d)
```

This has the disadvantage of mutating the input, so maybe another version that first copies `d` should be used. Still, there is a disadvantage of having to use a special method instead of the constructor, and not being able to insert `args` instead of a `dict` (what if I sometimes get a list of the values? Do I have to define `from_list` too? This is not nice!).

A similar option which does not modify the input would be to define `def from_dict(cls, **d):`. Or I can just define the `__new__` method like this:

```
class Payment(namedtuple("_Payment", ["date", "amount"])):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        kwargs["date"] = datetime.strptime(kwargs["date"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return super().__new__(cls, **kwargs)
```

which has the advantage of using the constructor instead of a special method. But its disadvantage is that I lose the ability to create the class using positional arguments.

So is there a more elegant way to create a `namedtuple` and modify a specific field of it?

Comment: " Still, there is a disadvantage of having to use a special method instead of the constructor" this really isn't a disadvantage. Indeed, that, I would say, is the "correct" way here, since it maintains consistency with the super-class (`tuple`). Using `classmethod` to create alternative constructors is very idiomatic. Honestly, you should probably just use a regular class, maybe using the `dataclasses.dataclass` decorator for convenience, rather than going through this rigamarole to shoe-horn your desired behavior into the `tuple` / `NamedTuple` interface

Comment: Honestly, the simplest solution is just do define the signature explicitly, ` def __new__(cls, date, amount)`. It doesn't matter if you are also doing that in the argument to the `namedtuple` class factory. Your other solutions are much more over-engineered to avoid repeating that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I never asked for a solution that does not maintain consistency with the super-class. Moreover, you ignored the second disadvantage I talked about: "and not being able to insert args instead of a `dict` (what if I sometimes get a list of the values? Do I have to define from_list too? This is not nice!)". Using a regular class I would have been able to just have one constructor that works for both `kwargs` and `args`, so I consider having 3 constructors that still don't cover all of the functionalities, a not so nice idea.

Comment: Using `dataclass` is a nice idea, I didn't know about it since I'm new to python 3. Thank you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why is your solution in the second comment better than defining `def from_dict(cls, **kwargs):`? Also, I don't understand your opinion about `dataclass` vs what you offered in the second comment.